# Is an HTTP Server a Good Idea For IPC?

Tags: linux, perl, rest, ipc, dancer

I need to implement a tool which gets its data from running processes,in a POST/GET mechanism. The amount of connections between the client/server is quite low - One request per minute on average.

The default way is to implement a simple server based on sockets and so on. However, I find it too much of a work for such a simple thing. There are plenty of tools out there, that are able to create an HTTP server with only 5 lines of coding (Perl Dancer, for example). Interfacing with them is fast and easy. Adding new functionality is as easy as it gets. Resources wise, they are pretty lightweight.

Is an HTTP server a bad idea for such a task (overhead-wise)? Is there a simple RESTful framework for IPC similar to Daner/node.js?

Thanks!

Comment: Go for it if you don't care about network latencies.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is, basically, a stateless protocol. You request something, the server replies, and that's the end of it. HTTP 1.1 has changed parts of the implementation, mainly for performance reasons, but it hasn't really changed the "client sends - server answers - transaction finished" pattern. Which means that if you want to implement locking mechanisms, synchronization, or transactions started by the server, you'll have to do a lot of coding to make HTTP do what it wasn't designed for.

This doesn't mean there's no way to do those things, it just means you might have to do a lot of coding to make the HTTP server do what you need. In the long run, it'll be easier to build a server for your specific needs than trying to abuse a HTTP server.

Of course, if what HTTP can do is sufficient for your current need, and if you're in an environment where quick coding is more important than performance and long-term maintainability, use an HTTP server. If you can do the job in one day, and know in advance the requirements won't change much, it doesn't make much sense to spend ten days to get a solution that has 3% better performance and 2% better maintainability.

Comment: TCP is basically stateless protocol. Which means that if you want to implement locking mechanisms, synchronization, or transactions started by the server, you'll have to do a lot of coding to make TCP do what it wasn't designed for. Guess he shouldn't use TCP either. That darn IP is even worse! Avoid that at all costs!

Comment: TCP is NOT a stateless protocol. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol#Stacking_of_stateless_and_stateful_protocol_layers if you don't believe me.

Comment: It doesn't have a concept of requests, so how can it maintain state between requests? The point was that you're blowing things out of proportion, especially when the OP mentioned that HTTP would be a layer under Dancer, which surely does support sessions.